# Installing WWW-development system on Macbook

Tags: git, macos, mamp

I tried to install git and Mamp to my Macbook. After I installed Mamp, I found a new folder under the applications folder. But as I installed git, I didn't find it under the applications folder. Am I doing everything OK and how can I test if git works correctly?

Comment: Please read our FAQ, this question is appropriate for our sister site stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

git is a command line application.  Open Terminal and type git, followed by Return.

It should print some help, similar to:

```
usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path]
       [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects]
       [--bare] [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>]
       [-c name=value] [--help]
       <command> [<args>]
```

If it says `command not found`, then either it is not installed, or not in the PATH.